Ошибка Duplicate class в проекте Android studio
Очень редко пишу приложения в Android studio. Когда-то написал для себя приложение. Потом только заходил периодически, чтобы обновлять его под требования Google. И вот в очередной раз нужно обновить его. Поставил новую студию 2024.2.1. Она сразу сказала, что у меня много всего устарело в проекте. Я всё пообновлял и проект больше не компилируется)
Ошибка:
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar -> jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21.jar -> jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar -> jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21.jar -> jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar -> jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21.jar -> jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar -> jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21.jar -> jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar -> jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21.jar -> jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)

И таких строк ещё несколько.  Kotlin в проекте не используется. Не соображу куда копать. Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Что пробовал и не помогло:

Очищать кэш
Отключать единственную библиотеку, которую подключал через JAR Dependency. Всё остальное стандартное
Искать в файлах проекта stdlib и удалять строки с версией 1.6.21


https://stackoverflow.com/q/75263047/13754729 тут много разных решений предлагают, может поможет

Проблема решается добавлением кода в build.gradle (:app):
configurations.implementation {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
}

Благодарю @Dev18
